# Can you have a GtkTreeView that only has checkboxes on the children rows?

Tags: checkbox, gtk, gtktreeview

I'd like to have a `GtkTreeView` that has parents with no checkbox, and all of the children have checkboxes. Everything I have tried (and seen) puts checkboxes on every row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the easiest way to do this is to put the checkbox in its own gtk.TreeViewColumn and have a column of data indicating whether it is visible or not. The visible column number is passed to gtk.TreeViewColumn. See the Tree View -> Tree Store demo that comes with Gtk+ for more details.